# yum install gcc-g++ doesn't work anymore in CentOs 6.4

Tags: linux, centos, yum

Today installed CentOs 6.4 fresh new on my workstation.

I wanted to install `g++`. With my surprise I didn't succeed by using

```
 yum install gcc-g++
```

The thing is that even by doing a search I don't get any result.

```
 # No package available
 yum search g++
```

On top of that I installed successfully `gcc`.

Do you know whether I am using the wrong package name or what should I do?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Have you tried:
 `yum install gcc-c++`

Comment: Wow... silly me, too. That's `c++` not `g++`!

Comment: This worked for me, after searched lot......Thanks again

Answer (score 10):

I was successful with on CentOS 6.4

```
    yum install gcc-c++.x86_64
```

Comment: Also worked for me on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this post because installing node with regular `gcc-c++` it will complain;

but to workaround the issue you can install `gcc-g++` from `Linuxsoft: Software Repository`

```
curl http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/scl/slc6-scl.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/slc6-scl.repo

rpm --import http://ftp.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/obsolete/51/i386/RPM-GPG-KEYs/RPM-GPG-KEY-cern

yum install -y devtoolset-3

scl enable devtoolset-3 bash
```

and node will be happy !

Answer (score 0):

One thing I have realized is that many packages give that error because package names are usually different than most tutorials out there on the net.

Normally when I get stuck I just use this command:

```
yum list | grep <packagename>
```

This gets a list of all packages like the one we are searching for and it always lists the full name which we should use to install the package.

Also the `<packagename>` is case-sensitive, geoip and GeoIP will return different list of packages.

Comment: You can make the match insensitive by using `grep -i <packagename>` instead.

Comment: `yum` has its own `search` command which looks in descriptions and urls as well as package names.